# Fast algorithm that can find an unknown grid destination on a 2d map build on the go

Tags: c++, graph-algorithm, path-finding, a-star, robotics

I have a rover that builds a map as it goes. It stores data about each grid location in a node. It stores if it has been explored/unexplored (that is if sensors have scan that grid location) or visited (the rover has been actual in that spot) or if it is blocked or not. I am using A* to help find paths. So going from a source location (the rovers location) to a destination location. Those destination locations are the unexplored parts of the map it is creating.

The data is stored in a linked lattice array, basically each node has 8 pointers to each surrounding grid location. each parent location that has been explored will create/populate surrounding nodes with unexplored. each explored node is labeled if it was visited/sensed, or if it is blocked/navigable. Unexplored is just null for everything expect the explored bit.

What i am looking for is an algorithm to help to find the next unexplored destination location. Most likely the closest one, but it has to be able to stay quick as the map size increases.

I tried creating a 2d array that is about 4 times the size of a unit node, but the problem i ran in to is when all the nodes in that size is explored, it fails. I was thinking of trying checking each node, spiraling outward from the source node. but that will be checking a lot of nodes that have already been seen and starts to get unwieldy as the map grows. the thing is that the outside perimeter will always have nodes unexplored. Also any nodes inside a large object. (I still need to find a way to changes those nodes).

I don't have any code yet.

What i expect is a quick algorithm that finds an unexplored location, so i can use that has my destination point in my A* path finding.

Answer (score 0):

You could have 2d arrays with "linked lattice" pointers to surrounding peers, so you can link to new surrounding areas without resizing the arrays.

```
struct Explored_index
{
    std::array<std::array<bool, N>, N> explored_;
    std::array<Explored_index*, 8> links_;  // say 0=North, clockwise
};
```

If you wanted this to scale arbitrarily, you could automate it so that once any 9 arrays were completely explored, it added a higher level index wherein each bit in the 2d array indicated whether the 2d array in the 2nd-highest index had been completely explored, but if this "rover" is in any way physical there are time constraints on how much it can explore and you probably don't need such scalability.